# What's in a name? Backoffice, backend, management tools,

Tags: c#, javascript, php, asp.net

As with many projects there is a website that many people can visit and there is a 'website' that only a few have access too to manage the content on the the main website.

But how do **you** call these 2 parts / projects?

- Front-end / Back-end
- Public / Backoffice
- Bonnie / Clyde
- ...

I like Front-end / Back-end but it's not 'correct'. Front-end is any UI and Back-end is the code behind the UI.

Any poets here? I'm looking for catchy names!

**[edit]**

These names are just for me as a developer to name my projects and to refer to them in any documentation.

**[edit2]**

Please post any proposal as an answer so I can pick a winner ;-)

Comment: Front-end and Back-end have specific meanings to web-developers, not necessarily to website visitors

Comment: `SeeStuff` / `DoStuff`

Comment: We most often refer to the administration panel/UI/page/site/thingie...

Comment: I believe the correct way would be to call the second part CMS and the main website simply that. Something catchier would be PublicFront/ManagementPortal

Answer (score 1):

To avoid confusion, you could use the term *Web Portal* to denote a *publicly* end point to which anyone with an internet connection can navigate to. On the other hand, you could use the term `Intranet Portal` to denote a portal which can be accessed only by people connected to a particular network.

In turn, these portals can have their own *Back Offices*, which are essentially other portals which expose a series of functionalities (usually administrative).

That being said, I think that you could use other terminologies, as long as you are consistent you should be fine.